# How do I update a variable that is defined using another variable?

Tags: python

I'm writing a game and I have two variables:

```
strength = 10
hp = 50 + (strength * 5)
```

I was able to build a system that lets me update the `strength` variable as well as other attributes, but I assumed `hp` would be updated when I updated `strength`, which isn't the case.

```
strength += skilladdnum
print("you now have", strength, "strength!")
```

Is there any way for `hp` to update when `strength` updates?

Comment: If you want `hp` to always be equal to `50 + strength * 5` (or some other formula), you could just define a function `get_hp()` that calculates and returns that value. Then just call `get_hp()` whenever you need the current `hp` value. This way you can also change the formula without needing to change your code everywhere.

Comment: You could also define a custom class for `hp` that uses this formula whenever it is used in a calculation or printed. But then you'd be reinventing `sympy`, so you might be better off using `sympy` if you want this behavior. The best option long-term is probably to create a class to manage all the character info, with getter/setter functions, as others have suggested.

Comment: @MatthiasFripp `sympy` is useless here. I'd stick with `get_hp()` inside a `player` class.

Comment: @Suthiro Practically speaking that may be true (I haven't used `sympy` much), but`sympy` is most similar to what @zephergoose was expecting, i.e., the ability to define one variable as being algebraically related to another one. But for a real application, I like @drew-e's solution best: a class that encompasses all hero attributes, and does whatever calculations are needed behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2):

On the level of language there is no way to somehow natively "tie together" twot variables so one would update automatically every time the other one gets updated if that's what you're thinking.

The proper way to do it would be to specify a "setter" function which you would call to update the strength and it would update also the hp.
So you could have something like

```
def set_strength(new_strength):
    return new_strength, 50 + (new_strength * 5)

strength, hp = set_strength(strength + skilladdnum)
```

but that's a bit ugly and does not feel idiomatic.
Once you get into [classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) and [object oriented programming](https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/) then you'll have e.g. class `Character` which will have fields (variables) `hp` and `strength` and from the outside of such class you would use only functions like `set_strength` and inside the class `Character` you would take care of updating them properly on all places.

Answer (score 1):

HP would go in a function, and you call it whenever you want its value:

```
strength = 50

def hp():
    return 50 + (strength * 5)
```

If this is used in a class, you can use the property decorator to get the value from the character: ie, character.strength, character.hp.  It would look similar:

```
class Hero:

    def __init__(self, strength):
        self.strength = strength
    
    @property
    def hp(self):
        return 50 + (self.strength * 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you would like `hp` to change whenever `strength` is updated, by the formula given as `hp = 50 + (strength * 5)`

However, when you assign `hp` in the line `hp = 50 + (strength * 5)` for the first time, you are initializing the variable `hp` to be the result of said formula at the given state. `hp` is not tied in any way to `strength` after the assignment.

Thus, you should update `hp` each time you update `strength`.

You can do this in a 'Pythonic' way with a function that updates both together to make it one line in the main code and cleaner. This can also be done in a more advanced fashion with a lambda or `property`.